# c++ move numbers to one side and letters to other one

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am learning C++ by solving problems. 
I need to make a program which will sort user's imputed text, by moving numbers to other side.

For example: the string "a13Bc1de2F G.! Hi8Kl90" -
Should look like : "aBcdeFGHiKl .! 1312890"

I only managed to make a program which will sort the text in alphabetical order.
I would like to have some guidance. I think that I need to check every character (if it's letter or number) and move to other string, but I am not sure exactly how to make it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>



using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1;
    cout << " Hi user! \n"
        "Imput some mess here: \n";
    cin >> str1;

    sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    cout << "Now it's not a mess : \n" << str1 << endl;


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just add a comparison function as the third parameter to sort.  The comparator should sort so that letters are case insentitive and punctuation comes after and numbers come last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do what you want. I've changed as little of the original code as possible.

The workhorse function is `move_digits_to_right`. We use the `isdigit` function from the `cctype` library, which checks if a given character is a digit. If so, we append it to the `digitVec` vector, otherwise, we append it to the `nonDigitVec` vector. At the end, we return a string beginning with the non digit characters, followed by the digit characters, while preserving their order of appearance in the original string.

Inside the `main` function, I've changed the `cin >> str1` line to `getline(cin, str)`. Otherwise, for your example input of `"a13Bc1de2F G.! Hi8Kl90"`, only the `"a13Bc1de2F"` portion will be read into `str1`. Using `getline(cin, str)` allows us to read the entire line of input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string move_digits_to_right(const string& s)
{
    vector<char> digitVec, nonDigitVec;
    int len = (int) s.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) {
            digitVec.push_back(s[i]);
        } else {
            nonDigitVec.push_back(s[i]);
        }
    }
    return string(nonDigitVec.begin(), nonDigitVec.end()) +
           string(digitVec.begin(), digitVec.end());
}

int main()
{
    string str1, output;
    cout << " Hi user! \n"
        "Imput some mess here: \n";
    getline(cin, str1);

    output = move_digits_to_right(str1);
    cout << "Now it's not a mess : \n" << output << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's was fast ,thank you, especially for pointing on "cctype" library and for the "getline". Now I have more stuff to read about.

Comment: no problem, always glad to help a fellow programmer. happy learning!